# _renderProxy has circular reference

Tags: vue.js

I get a circular reference error when trying to stringify an empty Vuex.Store.  I narrowed it down to this test case. I created this by using "vue create" to generate a new Vue application, then replacing main.js with this:

```
/* eslint no-console: 0 */
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";
import stringify from "json-stringify-safe";

Vue.use(Vuex);

console.log("**********************store:");
try {
 const store = new Vuex.Store({ state: {} });
 console.log(store);
 console.log(`state: ${JSON.stringify(store.state)}`);
 console.log("about to stringify");
 console.log(stringify(store));
 console.log("that worked")
 console.log("about to JSON.stringify");
 console.log(JSON.stringify(store));
} catch (e) {
 console.log("Unable to stringify new Vuex.Store({ state: {}, })");
 console.log(e);
}
```

The console output has the following:

```
**********************store:
main.js?56d7:11 Store {_committing: false, _actions: {…}, _actionSubscribers: Array(0), _mutations:      
{…}, _wrappedGetters: {…}, …}
main.js?56d7:12 state: {}
main.js?56d7:13 about to stringify
main.js?56d7:14 {"_committing":false,"_actions":{},"_actionSubscribers":[],"_mutations": 
{},"_wrappedGetters":{},"_modules":{"root":{"runtime":false,"_children":{},"_rawModule":{"state": 
{}},"state":{},"context":{}}},"_modulesNamespaceMap":{},"_subscribers":[],"_watcherVM": 
{"_uid":0,"_isVue":true,"$options":{"components":{},"directives":{},"filters":{},"beforeCreate": 
[null]},"_renderProxy":{"_uid":0,"_isVue":true,"$options":{"components":{},"directives":{},"filters": 
{},"beforeCreate":[null]},"_renderProxy":"[Circular ~._watcherVM._renderProxy]","_self":"[Circular 
~._watcherVM]","$root":"[Circular ~._watcherVM]","$children":
<etc -- stackoverflow won't let me put the entire stack trace here>
main.js?56d7:15 that worked
main.js?56d7:16 about to JSON.stringify
main.js?56d7:19 Unable to stringify new Vuex.Store({ state: {}, })
main.js?56d7:20 TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
--> starting at object with constructor 'Object'
--- property '_renderProxy' closes the circle
at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
at eval (main.js?56d7:17)
at Module../src/main.js (app.js:949)
at __webpack_require__ (app.js:849)
at fn (app.js:151)
at Object.1 (app.js:962)
at __webpack_require__ (app.js:849)
at checkDeferredModules (app.js:46)
at app.js:925
at app.js:928
```

The console log statement that uses json-stringify-safe library shows that there is a circular reference via _store._watcherVM._renderProxy._renderProxy.  The console log statement that uses JSON.stringify(store) statement fails because of this circular reference.

From further experiments, I found that I can avoid the circular references by setting store._watcherVM and store._vm to null while doing the stringify.

The reason I care about this is that the application depends upon a library that does JSON.stringify like this.  I can't replace that application.

Looking at the vue.js source code, I see that the Proxy structure is due to it.

This application hasn't changed in months, but I see from my source repo that it was last built with vue 2.5.22.  I'll try reverting to that and report the results.

My package file lists these dependencies:

```
 "core-js": "^3.6.5",
"json-stringify-safe": "^5.0.1",
"vue": "^2.6.11",
"vuex": "^3.6.2"
```

I am using node v10.23.0 on Windows 10.

Comment: I reverted to vue@2.5.22 and vuex@3.1.0 and node v10.15.0 -- none of those fixed the problem.

Comment: I found that I can hack around the stringify problem by saving and setting to null the following store fields and restoring them afterwards:

store._watcherVM, 
store._vm

These two fields are instances of Vue which has a _self field that makes for the circular reference.